# Customising Google Maps control for Android 10

Tags: android, google-maps, android-10.0

How to remove the **Direction and Map** icon from Android Google Maps. This icons will get displayed when we tap on the Pushpin in the map. I am trying to programmatically hide this option in Android Map control. Can anyone help me to find a solution for this.?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

> Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or
> disabled. If enabled, and the Map Toolbar can be shown in the current
> context, users will see a bar with various context-dependent actions,
> including 'open this map in the Google Maps app' and 'find directions
> to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps app'.
>
> By default, the Map Toolbar is enabled.

More settings: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/UiSettings

Comment: Thank you. You save my day.